# Spark not running RDD in Parallel Pyspark with binaryfile

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new beginner to Spark and started to write some script in Python. My understanding is that Spark executes the Transformation in parallel (map).

```
def some_function(name, content):
    print(name, datetime.now())
    time.sleep(30)
    return content

config = SparkConf().setAppName("sample2").setMaster("local[*]")
filesRDD = SparkContext(conf=config).binaryFiles("F:\\usr\\temp\\*.zip")
inputfileRDD = filesRDD.map(lambda job_bundle: (job_bundle[0], some_function(job_bundle[0], job_bundle[1])))
print(inputfileRDD.collect())
```

The above code collects list of `.zip` files from a folder and processes it. When I execute it I am seeing this is happening sequentially.

Output

```
file:/F:/usr/temp/sample.zip 2020-10-22 10:42:37.089085
file:/F:/usr/temp/sample1.zip 2020-10-22 10:43:07.103317
```

You can see that it started processing 2nd file after 30 sec. meaning after completing the first file. What went wrong in my code ? why it is not executing RDD in parallel ? Can you please help me ?

Comment: How many cores do you have on your machine?

Comment: @Oli  have 4 core on my machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly how the method `binaryFiles` partitions the files accross spark partitions. It seems that contrarily to `textFiles`, it tends to only create one partition. Let's see that with an example directory called `dir` and containing 5 files.

```
> ls dir
test1  test2  test3  test4  test5
```

If I use `textFile`, things are run in parallel. I don't provide the output because it is not very pretty but you can check yourself. We can verify that things are run in parallel with `getNumPartitions`.

```py
>>> sc.textFile("dir").foreach(lambda x: some_function(x, None))
# ugly output, but everything starts at the same time,
# except maybe the last one since you have 4 cores.
>>> sc.textFile("dir").getNumPartitions()
5
```

With `binaryFiles` things are different and for some reason everything goes to the same partition.

```py
>>> sc.binaryFiles("dir").getNumPartitions()
1
```

I even tried with 10k files and everything still goes to the same partition. I believe the reason behind that is that in scala, `binaryFiles` returns a RDD with file names and an object that allows to read the files (but no reading is performed). Therefore it is fast, and the resulting RDD is small. Therefore, having it on one partition is OK.
In scala, we can thus use repartition after using `binaryFiles` and things will work great.

```scala
scala> sc.binaryFiles("dir").getNumPartitions
1
scala> sc.binaryFiles("dir").repartition(4).getNumPartitions
4
scala> sc.binaryFiles("dir").repartition(4)
    .foreach{ case (name, ds) => { 
        println(System.currentTimeMillis+": "+name)
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        // do some reading on the DataStream ds
    }}
```

```
1603352918396: file:/home/oanicol/sandbox/dir/test1
1603352918396: file:/home/oanicol/sandbox/dir/test3
1603352918396: file:/home/oanicol/sandbox/dir/test4
1603352918396: file:/home/oanicol/sandbox/dir/test5
1603352920397: file:/home/oanicol/sandbox/dir/test2
```

The problem in python is that `binaryFiles` actually reads the file onto one single partition. Also, that's extremely mysterious to me but the following lines of code in pyspark 2.4 yield the same behaviour you notice which does not make sense.

```py
# this should work but does not
sc.binaryFiles("dir", minPartitions=4).foreach(lambda x: some_function(x, ''))
# this does not work either, which is strange but it would not be advised anyway
# since all the data would be read on one partition
sc.binaryFiles("dir").repartition(4).foreach(lambda x: some_function(x, ''))
```

Yet, since `binaryFiles` actually reads the file, you can use `wholeTextFile` which reads the file as a text file and behaves as expected:

```py
# this works
sc.wholeTextFiles("dir", minPartitions=4).foreach(lambda x: some_function(x, ''))
```